# Email-similar regex catastrophic backtracing

Tags: regex

I'd like to match something which may be called the beginning of the e-mail, ie.

1. 1 character (whichever letter from alphabet and digits)
2. 0 or 1 dot
3. 1 or more character
4. The repetition of {2nd and 3rd point} zero or more times
5. *@* character

The regex I've been trying to apply on [Regex101](https://regex101.com) is `\w(\.?\w+)*@`.

I am getting the error *Catastrophic backtracking*. What am I doing wrong? Is the regex correct?

Comment: What test string(s) are giving that error?

Comment: I am applying this regex to http://pastebin.com/dQwUHeS0

Comment: In particular this form of assignment, but the question in general is about matching this type of text. And I know "one can't parse [X]HTML with regex" :)

Comment: I think the site you're using may be the problem.  If I put the contents of the pastebin into a file and run your regex through grep, I get a result:

`    $ cat testfile | egrep '\w(\.?\w+)*@'
    
    <FONT SIZE=-1>Pytania i uwagi dotyczące archiwum: <A HREF="mailto:archmin@rzeczpospolita.pl">archmin@rzeczpospolita.pl</A><BR>

    $`

Comment: Oh, this is weird. I want only match `archmin@`

Comment: You can use `-o` for that.  `egrep -o '\w(\.?\w+)*@'`

Comment: You actually need `\w(\.\w+)*@` rather than `\w(\.?\w+)*@`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The original question said 0 or 1 dots.

Comment: 1 or 0? `\w(\.\w+)?@`

Comment: For example `aaa.aaaaaa.a.aa.aa` but now `aaa..aaaa.a`

Comment: Sorry, I meant `\w+(\.\w+)?@` but now I see that you need `\w+(\.\w+)*@`, or even `^\w+(\.\w+)*@`

Comment: I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usual for [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) to appear in cases of nested quantifiers when the group inside contains at least one optional subpattern, *making the quantified subpattern match the same pattern as the subpattern before the outer group* and the outer group is not at the end of the pattern.

[Your regex causes the issue](https://regex101.com/r/oOwwww/1)  right because the `(\.?\w+)*` is not at the end, there is an optional `\.?` and the expression is reduced to [`\w(\w+)*@`](https://regex101.com/r/oOwwww/2).

> For example `aaa.aaaaaa.a.aa.aa` but now `aaa..aaaa.a`

What you need is

```
^\w+(?:\.\w+)*@
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oOwwww/3)

- `^` - start of string (to avoid partial matches)
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `(?:\.\w+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `\.` - a literal dot
  - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
- `@` -  a literal `@` char.

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

"Catastrophic backtracing" occurs when a part of the string could match a part of the regex in many different ways, so it needs to repeatedly retry to determine whether or not the string actually matches. A simple case: The regex `a+a+b` to match two or more `a` followed by one `b`. If you were to run that on `aaaaaaaaaaa`, the problem arises: First, the first `a+` matches everything, and it fails at the second `a+`. Then, it tries with the first `a+` matching all but one `a`, and the second `a+` matches one `a` (this is "backtracing"), and then it fails on the `b`. But regexes aren't "smart" enough to know that it could stop there - so it has to keep going in that pattern until it's tried every split of giving some `a`s to the first and some to the second. Some regex engines will realize they're getting stuck like this, and quit after enough steps, with the error you saw.

For your specific pattern: what you have there matches any nonzero quantity of letters or digits, mixed with any quantity of `.` where the `.` cannot be first, followed by an `@`. The only additional limit is that there can't be two adjacent dots. Effectively, this is the same case as my example: The `*` applied to a section containing a `+` acts like multiple duplicates of that `+`-ed section.

### Atomic grouping

You could try something with [atomic grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html). That basically says "once you've found any match for this, don't backtrace into it". After all, if you've found some amount of `/w`, it's not going to contain a `/.` and there's no need to keep rechecking that - dots are not letters or digits, and neither of those is an `@`.

In this case, the result would be `\w(?>\.?\w+)*@`. Note that not all regex engines support atomic grouping, though the one you linked does. If the string is only a match, nothing will change - if it's not a match, or contains non-matches, the process will take fewer steps. Using @eddiem's example from the comments, it finds two matches in 166311 steps with your original, but only takes 623 steps with atomic grouping added.

### Possessive quantifiers

Another option would be a possessive quantifier - `\w(\.?\w+)*+@` means roughly the same thing. `*+`, specifically, is "whatever the star matches, don't backtrace inside it". In the above case, it matches in 558 steps - but it's slightly different meaning, in that it treats all the repeats together as one atomic value, instead of as several distinct atomic values. I don't think there's a difference in this case, but there might be in some cases. Again, not supported by all regex engines.

Comment: Unfortunately I do want not to have two dots together.

Comment: @BartłomiejSzałach Adjusted.